# Install wkhtmltopdf in a Mac in order to be used by imgkit gem in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use IMGKit gem. 
So I need to install wkhtmtopdf software.

The following command doesn't work: sudo imgkit --install-wkhtmltoimage   , so I am trying to install it manually.

I downloaded two versions for Mac: one is a .i386 file and the other are 4 .dylib files.

How can I install any of them? 
Why they dont have a normal installer?

Comment: The first google result is http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ --- you can download the shell binaries there depending on your OS and 32bit vs 64 bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.i386 file can be copied directly to /usr/local/bin and I had to make it executable chmod u+x NAMEOFTHEFILE.i386

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation) a gander. It simplifies the process of installing many tools and libraries on OSX.